# What is a subspace of a dimension in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

The documentation of torch.Tensor.view says:

> each new view dimension must either be a ***subspace*** of an original dimension, or only span across original dimensions ...

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view

What is a subspace of a dimension?

Comment: @moisrex What does that mean? You're linking to the concept of a vector subspace. Are you implying that a view is a vector subspace?

Comment: * a vector space?

Answer (score 3):

## The 'subspace of an original dimension' dilemma

In order to use `tensor.view()` the tensor must satisfy two conditions-
each new view dimension must either be a

1. `subspace of an original dimension`
2. `or only span across original dimensions ...`

Lets discuss this one by one,

**First**, regarding `subspace of an original dimension` you need to understand the concept behind subspace. Not going into mathematical detail but in short - subspace is a subset of infinite number of n dimensional vectors(Rn) and the vectors inside the subspace must follow 2 rules -

i) *Sub space will contain the Zero vector(0n)*

ii) *Must satisfy closure under Multiplication and addition*

To visualise this in mind you can consider a 2D plane containing infinite lines. So the subspace of that 2D vector space will be set of lines which will pass through origin. These lines satisfies above two conditions.

Now there is a concept called **projection of subspaces**. Without digging into too much mathematical detail you can consider it as a regular line projection but for subspaces.

Now back to the point, lets assume if you have a tensor of size `(4,5)`, you can actually consider it as a 20 dimensional vector. Assume you have a 20D space, and the subspaces will pass through the origin, and if you want to make projection of any line l1 from subspace with respect to any 2 axes, `tensor.view()` will output projection of that line with `(2,10)`.

For **the second part**, you need to understand the concept of `contiguous` and `non-contiguous` memory allocation in pytorch. As its out of scope of the question I am going to explain it in very brief. If you view a `n` dimensional vector as `(n/k, k)` and if you run tensor.stride() on the new vector it will show you the stride for memory allocation in x and y direction. Now if you run view() again with different dimensions then this following equation must hold true for successful conversion due to `non-contiguous` memory allocation.

[image]

I tried my best to explain it in brief, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I do not quite understand this answer. Could you clarify this part: "...,and if you want to make projection of a line l1 from subspace with respect to first 2 axes. So the `tensor.view()` will output projection of that line with `(2,10)`." In particular what do you mean by projection "with respect to" the first 2 axes, are you saying that the projection is *onto* the plane spanned by the first two axes?

Comment: Yeah that I feel that was poorly explained, but what I wanted to express in that part is lets assume if you have a vector of (10,) and you you want to view it from one extra dimension it will be viewed as (1,10). Or if you go inside each element of (10,) and view it with an extra dimension it will be (10,1). Now consider this for (4,5) it can be interpreted as (20,) now if you want to view it with respect to two dimensions it will be (2, 10).  You can further extend this to let say (2, 2, 5) if you want to see those 10d vectors inside the (2,10) from another 2 dimensions.

Comment: Do you have a shareable source to study the concept of  *projection of subspaces*?

Comment: There are several resources on that topic you can search it on google, but I think this might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112743

Comment: If your interpretation is correct, why would for example `torch.t(torch.full((4,5),2)).view(2,10)` produce an error? Sure it does not satisfy the second condition, but based on your writing I don't see why it would not satisfy the first condition, "subspace of an original dimension". Granted, I still don't quite understand how  you have answered the question what a subspace of an original dimension is.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you in your example explained, for each new dimension, how is it a subspace of an old dimension.

Answer (score 2):

After some thought, I think the sentence could be interpreted as follows (despite not being mathematically formal).

Suppose to have a `tensor` `t` of size `(4, 6)`, that can be seen as an ordered set of four 6d row vectors residing in a vector space.

We can perform a tensor view `v = t.view(4, 2, 3)`. `v` has now two new view dimensions: 2 and 3. We can see it as an ordered set containing four ordered sets of two 3d vectors, or three 2d vectors, depending on how we consider them.

Such new, smaller vectors can be mathematically seen as projections of the original 6-element vectors onto a vector subspace.